# Can you see a maps pin on an iPhone placed by a different person with the same app?

Tags: ios, ios6-maps

I'm creating an app and want to know before I go further if within an app is it possible to place a pin on maps on one iPhone, and then in the same app on a different iPhone have that pin show up on the second phones' map? If so how?

Person A places pin. Person B sees Person A's pin on their map?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes. Send the data to a server, and then have the other phone get the data. Or use GameKit to temporarily connect the devices and share the data or use …

Comment: Found this just after I posted my questions. Will something like this work?                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056176/how-to-create-a-server-accessible-by-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, that's not how maps works. You'd need to implement some kind of network service to record when users place pins and distribute that information to other relevant users' copies of the app, so that it can display the pins.

Comment: what kind of network service do you mean/recommend? I'm kinda new to ios, I don't know much about it.